# Function which is Riemann integrable on $ [c,b] $ for $ c \in (a,b) $ but not integrable on $ [a,b] $.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

What are some common, preferably uncomplicated functions $ f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ that are Riemann integrable on $ [c,b] $ for all $ c \in (a,b) $ but not integrable on $ [a,b] $.

I know $ f = 1/x $ is one such function for the interval $ [0,1] $. Are there any other examples?

Comment: You can always change variables, say $f(x) = \sin (1/(5x+3))$ is another example when you choose $a,b$ correctly (like $a=-\frac{3}{5}, b=1$)

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're trying to say, but note that $[a, b]$ cannot be the domain of $f$ in your example: note that $f(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: @Clarinetist True but this can be fixed by forcing $f(0)=0$.

Comment: yes, this was what I meant -- $ f(x) = 1/x $ for $ (0,1] $, and $ f(x) = 0 $ for $ x=0 $. cheers

Comment: Do you know Lebesgue measure zero set and Lebesgue's Riemann integrability criterion?

Comment: @edm: Lebesgue criterion is not really needed here. Under the conditions of the question, the function has to be unbounded in neighborhood of $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any unbounded function $f$ on the closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b]$ is an example.

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not true. E.g. $\int_0^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm dx = 2 \sqrt{b}$.

Comment: @katosh  $1/\sqrt x$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,b],$ because it's not bounded on $[0,b].$ However the improper Riemann integral $\int_0^b (1/\sqrt x)dx$ exists.

Comment: Ok, I assumed that OP includes improper Riemann integrals since otherwise the answer seems so trivial. I mean, taking any continuous function and removing $a$ from its domain makes the integral improper.

Answer (score 1):

$ sin(1/x) $ is integrable on $ [0,1] $, integral converges to $sin(1)-cosintegral(1)=0.504067...$

Correct example is $ sin(1/x) /x $

Answer (score 1):

You can construct many more functions by first selecting a differentiable $F\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb R$, that is not defined or infinity at $x=a$ and finite for $x\in(a,b]$. Then just take the derivative as your example $f(x) := \frac{d}{dx}F(x)$.

For example, with all differentiable functions $g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with $\lim_{x\to-\infty}|g(x)|\to\infty$, you can construct
$$
F(x) = g\circ\log(x)\\
f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}F(x) = \frac{g'\circ\log(x)}{x}
$$
This way you know
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm dx = F(b) - F(a)
$$
which is finite for $a,b>0$ but undefined if $a=0$.